# Align UIView in the center of parent view by autoresizingMask in iOS 8

Tags: ios8, autoresizingmask

I have an app which is not using auto layout. Instead I'm using autoresizingMask. It works well in iOS 7. And it also works fine in iOS 8 when I start the app in portrait mode (it's still fine even when I rotate the device afterwards). Here is the screenshot when it's correct:

[image]

Here is my source code:

```
CGFloat w = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width;
CGFloat h = 100;
CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h);

UIView* view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
view1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[self.view addSubview:view1];

CGRect rect2 = CGRectMake(10, 105, 748, 50);
UIView* view2 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:rect2];
view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
view2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
[self.view addSubview:view2];
```

The problem occurs when I start my app in landscape mode. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Can anybody tell what I did wrong in my code? Thanks

Comment: I strongly suspect it's another bug of iOS 8.

Comment: Still can't solve the problem. Anybody have the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code a bit:

```
CGRect rect2 = CGRectMake((w-748)/2, 105, 748, 50);
```

This works as I expected.